# How can I trigger a ColumnLayout re-layout?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have some `Text` elements with `textFormat: Text.RichText`.  When the images load in, the `Text` expands, but the layout doesn't recalculate and hence the elements overlap:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
  ColumnLayout {
    Repeater {
      model: [1,2];
      delegate: Item {
        id: item;
        height: sample_col.height;
        ColumnLayout {
          id:sample_col
          Text { text: 'sample_col.height=' + sample_col.height + 
                       ' item.height=' + item.height; }
          Text {
            id: expanded_sample_html;
            textFormat: Text.RichText;
            text: '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/06/Kitten_in_Rizal_Park%2C_Manila.jpg">';
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When the image finally downloads to the app, I see:

[image]

So, the `Text`'s overlap after the image is loaded since the height is correct, but it doesn't flow up to the parent `ColumnLayout`.

How can I trigger the top, parent `ColumnLayout` to redraw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be using the attached `Layout` properties when working with Layout Types.

Having to explicitly  create declarative functionality is a good sign something is missing or code should be refactored.

```
Flickable {
    anchors.fill: parent
    contentWidth: mainColumn.width
    contentHeight: mainColumn.height
    ColumnLayout {
        id: mainColumn
        Repeater {
            model: [1,2];
            delegate: Item {
                id: item;
                Layout.preferredWidth: sample_col.width
                Layout.preferredHeight: sample_col.height
                ColumnLayout {
                    id:sample_col
                    Text { text: 'sample_col.height=' + sample_col.height +
                                 ' item.height=' + item.height; }
                    Text {
                        id: expanded_sample_html;
                        textFormat: Text.RichText;
                        text: '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/06/Kitten_in_Rizal_Park%2C_Manila.jpg">';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```